# image and textbox align with each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an event list with image on the left hand side, and text box on the right hand side describing it (similar to evenbrite). However, I am having the following issues:

1. creating a box for the text
2. align the image with the box
3. change the padding, margin of the text so that it fits inside the box.

Thank you!

html:

```
<img src="bionic.jpg" alt="festo bionic" class="events">
    <div class="event_description">
        <p> Robotics Demo </p>
        <p> All Day on October 4th, 2018. R:Lab, Emirates Tower</p>
        <p> Join us in interacting with the most technologically advanced robots. </p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    color: rgb(65, 56, 50);
    font-size: 6em;
    padding: 0px;
}
h2 {
    color: rgb(61, 23, 30);
    font-size: 3em;
}
img {
    height: 350px;
}
p {
    color: rgb(61, 23, 30);
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.events {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.event_description {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    float:right;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border:5px lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I have made the width of event_description

```
 width: calc(100% - 240px);
```

This will align the description next to image

**How this works**

```
width: calc(100% - 240px);
```

> 240px is sum of width of the image and the margin applied to the image

You are subtracting 240px from the width of the parent.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(65, 56, 50);
  font-size: 6em;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  color: rgb(61, 23, 30);
  font-size: 3em;
}

img {
  height: 350px;
}

p {
  color: rgb(61, 23, 30);
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.events {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.event_description {
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="festo bionic" class="events">
<div class="event_description">
  <p> Robotics Demo </p>
  <p> All Day on October 4th, 2018. R:Lab, Emirates Tower</p>
  <p> Join us in interacting with the most technologically advanced robots. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if that's what you want.

I created an element `<div class="content"></div>` which will be the parent of the elements, and set the following property: `display: flex;`.

To set the border of `.events_description` the added `solid`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

p {
    color: rgb(61, 23, 30);
}

.events {
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.event_description {
  flex-wrap:wrap;

    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px 15px 0 0;
    border:5px solid lightgray;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed1.jpg" alt="festo bionic" class="events">
  <div class="event_description">
    <p> Robotics Demo </p>
    <p> All Day on October 4th, 2018. R:Lab, Emirates Tower</p>
    <p> Join us in interacting with the most technologically advanced robots. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes sense. I edited a few, and found out that the text cannot be moved to the top left corner. I have tried editing the padding and margin, but that is about the box, not the test message. What do you recommend me doing in this case? Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer. The default `p` element has `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. In my answer I removed this margin and the `padding-left` and `padding-top` of the `.event_description`. See if this is what you are looking for